# How do I make the text in this menu appear on the right and the items on the left?

Tags: swiftui

By default, the menu label is on the left and the menu items are on the right. I want to reverse this and make the menu label on the right and the menu items on the left. How can I achieve this using SwiftUI?

```
Menu {
                        Button(action: { sortingType = .date }) {
                            Label("Sort by Date", systemImage: sortingType == .date ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                        }
                        Button(action: { sortingType = .amount }) {
                            Label("Sort by Amount", systemImage: sortingType == .amount ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                        }
                        
                    }
```

[image: Image of the menu]

Comment: Provide your code. Can't debug the image.

Comment: Menu {
                        Button(action: { sortingType = .date }) {
                            Label("Sort by Date", systemImage: sortingType == .date ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                        }
                        Button(action: { sortingType = .amount }) {
                            Label("Sort by Amount", systemImage: sortingType == .amount ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                        }
                        
                    }

Comment: I add an answer, so please check if it's working.

Answer (score -1):

Try to call the label and the condition in **reverse**.

```
Menu {
    Button(action: { sortingType = .date }) {
        Label(systemImage: sortingType == .date ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle", "Sort by Date")
    }
    Button(action: { sortingType = .amount }) {
        Label(systemImage: sortingType == .amount ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle", "Sort by Amount")
    }
}
```

*(additional)*

How 'bout this one? Separating label and your icon.

```
Button(action: { sortingType = .date }) {
    Label {
        Text("Sort by Date")
    } icon: {
        Image(systemImage: sortingType == .date ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
    }
}
Button(action: { sortingType = .amount }) {
    Label {
        Text("Sort by Amount")
    } icon: {
        Image(systemImage: sortingType == .amount ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
    }
}
```

Isn't still working?

Comment: It didn't unfortunately, I got this error Replace 'systemImage: sortingType == .date ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle", "Sort by Date"' with '"Sort by Date", systemImage: sortingType == .date ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle"'

Comment: Can I ask what type of error is showing?

Comment: There is additional in my answer. Please try it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I encountered an error when I tried your suggestion. Here is the error message: Extraneous argument label 'systemImage:' in call, Remove 'systemImage: '.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help. If possible, please make an playground of your work so it can be check or debug easily.